# Kendo MVC call javascript from a template

Tags: model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I have a telerik  mvc grid (NOT JAVASCRIPT) with groupable() turned on.  The column i am grouping by has a link in it.  No big deal since that's easy on a column template.  However, header templates don't allow access to data from a column different that the one the grouping is set on, and our links are all based on the "ID" column (hidden) whereas the grouping is on the "Name" column.
Can I call javascript from the header template to get the data I need?
here is an example of what has worked

```
    .Groupable()
                .Selectable()
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("#= rowCommandsUndelete(data, false, true) #").Title("&nbsp;").Width(100);
                    columns.Bound(m => m.Active)
                        .Title("Active?")
                        .ClientTemplate("#= ActiveState(data.Active) #")
                        .Width(85);
                    columns.Bound(m => m.Origin.Name)
                        .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("<a href='www.google.com'>link </a>")
                        .ClientTemplate("<div id='#=data.ID#'></div><a href='/Origins?id=#=data.Origin.ID#'>#=data.Origin.Name#</a>")  //Empty div with "data.ID" is required (see JavaScript section below)
                        .Width(300);
```

and this doesn't work and gives an error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ID' of undefined

```
     columns.Bound(m => m.Origin.Name)
                        .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("<a href='www.google.com'> #=data.Origin.ID#</a>")
```

Comment: Consider not shouting in the question subject.

Comment: You should bound "Origin", not "Origin.Name". Because you can access in "ClientGroupHeaderTemplate" the "value" property (the current group value), not "data.Origin" or another column. So, your client template will be same and "ClientGroupHeaderTemplate" will be like that:
`.ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("<a href='/Origins?id=#=value.ID#'>#=value.Name#</a>")`
It's exemplary code, so there is maybe some syntactic errors, sorry.

Comment: also, i evidently didn't shout loud enough.  The only answer i got was in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's [groupHeaderTemplate](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.groupheadertemplate) configuration.

[Example](https://dojo.telerik.com/azEKunod):

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { field: "link",
      groupHeaderTemplate: "<a href=#=value# target='_blank'>google.com</a>"
    }
  ],
  dataSource: {
    data: [
      { name: "Jane Doe", link: "https://google.com" },
      { name: "John Doe", link: "https://google.com" }
    ],
    group: { field: "link" }
  }
});
```

Comment: our code is in c# but i think i can convert this.  I'll get back to you and let you know how well this worked for me.

Comment: i was able to use your example to point me in the right place to put the clientgroupheadertemplate(i'm using an ajax page) but it's not letting me access data from it.  Any ideas?

Comment: so i was able to use clientgroupheader to call a javascript and return a value to the template that way.  This pointed me in the correct direction so i'm accepting it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

the final answer is thanks to sandro.  On an ajax page, use clientgroupheadertemplate like this on a column:

```
     columns.Bound(m => m.Origin.Name)
                        .ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#=buildHeader( value )#")
```

buildheader is a javascript function, and value is a built-in value in the header.  Here's the javascript function:

```
  function buildHeader(value) {
    return "<h4><u><a href='\origins?OriginName=" + encodeURIComponent(value) + "'>" + value + "</a></u></h4>";
}
```

value contained the string from the column and i was able to create a link this way and set it to the column header.  I have also successfully called javascript now from a footer to trigger something after a calculation.

Comment: as a side note:  I am aware in this example i could have just hardcoded the url in the headertext.  However the original goal was to get the id and set the link like that.  We ended up just creating a separate filter on the mvc page making it unnecessary to parse the grid for the correct id.